# FormArray should be invalid when the FormArray is empty

Tags: angular

I have created form with FormArray like below mentioned

```
    this.createModuleForm = this.fb.group({
        artefactType: ['', Validators.required],
        uploadDocuments: this.fb.array([]),
    });
```

then I'm pushing the object into the FormArray

```
        formArray.push(this.fb.group({name: event.name, url: event.url, submittedBy: 'siva', role: this.currentUser.value.role}));
```

Problem: If the uploadDocuments(FormArray) is empty, need to make Form is invalid and UploadDocuments should be mandatoary

Comment: You can do via check length uploadDocuments formArray in template

Comment: use ``FormArray.setErrors()`` to set your errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create custom Validator

I have created minAdded function that will check wheather the current formarray has minimum one group or not

**component.ts**

```
 this.createModuleForm = this.fb.group({
        artefactType: 'De',
        uploadDocuments: this.fb.array([], minAdded(1))
 })

    function minAdded(min = 1) {
      const validator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: FormArray) => {
        const minAdded = formArray.controls
          .map(control => control.value).length;    
        return minAdded >= min ? null : { required: true };
      };    
   return validator;
 }
```

Ref: https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular
Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcy9z9